# I want when touched a row then its color changes to BLue. and when finger got out returns to default?

Tags: android, xml, touch, background-color, tablerow

I have a xml file for my android app.at this xml file there are some TableRows. I want when user touches each rows then color of row changes. i am new to android and got some code for this changing but those couldn't help me.
I write these codes but I m not certain for accuracy at all.please help.
I want when touched a row then its color changes to BLue. and when finger got out returns to default? But how?

```
enter code here <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- When selected, use blue color for bachground row  -->
<item 
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/item_backgroundcolor_blue" />  

<!-- When not selected, use no color for bachground row -->   
 <item ?????????????????????????? />
```

this is "item_backgroundcolor_blue" in "drawable"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<color android:color="@color/LightBlue"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/holo_blue_overlay" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/holo_blue_overlay" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/holo_blue_overlay" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

Comment: I use transparent in last line like you.But background rows change to black!But I with see this event remove my code!

Comment: Change to black when ? If you row item is black when not clicked, that has to do with the xml for your row item. If it changes to black when clicked, something is wrong with the way you define your colors in colors.xml.

Comment: I will test and tell result by an answer.

Comment: another question please: I have an selector for my buttons which changes buttons layout when clicked.but when I add that selector for my togglebutton then defualt layout (default pic that has on off ) is gone.I dont want removing default style.but how?

Answer (score 1):

Heloo.I found that for using a selector like above must be have OnClickListener Method not OnTochListeners.for this reason my code dindnt work.